# SML/NJ: How to use HashTable?

Tags: structure, hashtable, sml, smlnj

I really want to create a HashTable in SML, it seems there already is a structure for this in SML/NJ.

The question is, how do I use it? I've not fully understood how to use structures in SML, and some of the very basic examples in the book I read gives me errors I don't even know how to correct, so using the HashTable structure might be an easy thing, but I wouldn't know. If someone could explain this, then that'd be wonderful too!

I'm thinking it's something like this:

```
val ht : string * int HashTable.hash_table = HashTable.mkTable();
```

???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The signature of the `mkTable` value is:

```
val mkTable : (('a -> word) * (('a * 'a) -> bool)) -> (int * exn)
      -> ('a,'b) hash_table
    (* Given a hashing function and an equality predicate, create a new table;
     * the int is a size hint and the exception is to be raised by find.
     *)
```

Therefore, you would have to do something like:

```
val ht : (string, int) HashTable.hash_table =
    HashTable.mkTable (HashString.hashString, op=) (42, Fail "not found")
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked. So it set the default size at 42 then, and will automatically increase in size when more than that is added?

Answer (score 5):

I assume the idea is to create a table mapping strings to integers. Then you want to write its type as `(string, int) hash_table` (the type `hash_table` is a type with two parameters, which are written like that in ML).

But you also need a hash function `hash : string -> word` and an equality function `eq : string * string -> bool` over strings to provide to `mkTable`. For the latter, you can simply use `op=`, for the former you can use `HashString.hashString` from the respective module.

So,

```
val ht : (string, int) HashTable.hash_table = HashTable.mkTable(HashString.hashString, op=)(17, Domain)
```

should work.

I should note, however, that hash tables tend to be vastly overused, and more often than not they are the wrong data structure. This is especially true in functional programming, since they are a stateful data structure. Usually you are better off (and potentially even more efficient) using some tree-based map, e.g., the `RedBlackMapFn` from the SML/NJ library.

Comment: You are correct in assuming I want a string mapped to an integer. When I used the line you wrote that you said should work, I get this error: `Error: pattern and expression in val dec don't agree [tycon mismatch] pattern: (string,int) HashTable.hash_table expression: int * exn -> (string,`Z) HashTable.hash_table in declaration: ht : (string, int) HashTable.hash_table = HashTable.mkTable (HashString.hashString,=)`. I did copy/paste the line you wrote.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot the second pair of arguments. Fixed.